# Action required: JavaScript SDK v2.19.2 is no longer supported by this application

Tags: launchdarkly

Updating JavaScript SDK v2.19.2 to latest version

"Action required: JavaScript SDK v2.19.2 is no longer supported Please update your application to the latest version".

Has anyone done this update before. Do I just click the "latest version" to update?

Answer (score 0):

This means that one or more of your applications uses the LaunchDarkly JS client with an outdated version.

Most probably it looks something like that in your package.json:

```
 "launchdarkly-js-client-sdk": "^2.18.3",
 // or maybe:
 "launchdarkly-react-client-sdk": "^2.18.0",
```

You should update the version to the latest, and then re-build and deploy your app the way you usually do so the new code is used.